# how to decode url (http:/\/\test) into (http://test) in php?

Tags: php, html, decode

I'm making a form in HTML and inside this form, there is some input text like URL, parameter, radio button and inside the radio button also have the same input like URL and parameter. After submitting my form, I want these data to save in a file format .txt, but I found a problem that URL saved in this file is `http:/\/\test` but if I show the data submitted with `var_dump($data)` URL is showing in `http://test`

I tried to use `urldecode($data)` but the result is still the same

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $nameURL = $_POST['nameURL'];
    $param = $_POST['param'];

    if($_POST['radiobutton']=='asynchronous'){
        $asyncURL = $_POST['asyncURL'];
        $asyncParam = $_POST['asyncParam'];

        $data = array(
            "Callback" => urldecode($nameURL),
            "Param" => $param,
            "asynchronous" => array(
                "Callback" => $asyncURL = urldecode($asyncURL),
                "Param" => array(
                            $asyncParam
                           )
            )
        );
    }else if($_POST['radiobutton']=='synchronous'){
        $syncURL = $_POST['syncURL'];
        $syncParam = $_POST['syncParam'];

        $data = array(
            "Callback" => urldecode($nameURL),
            "Param" => $param,
            "synchronous" => array(
                "Callback" => urldecode($syncURL),
                "Param" => array(
                            $syncParam
                           )
            )
        );
    }

    $data = json_encode($data);

    $filename = date('YmdHis').".txt";
    if(!file_exists($filename)){
        $fh = fopen($filename, 'w') or die("Can't create file!");
    }
    $ret = file_put_contents($filename, $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret == false){
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
```

and my HTML form

```
    <form id="myform">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="url" name="nameURL" id="nameURL" placeholder="URL">
            <input type="text" id="param" name="param[]" placeholder="Param">
            <input type="button" onclick="addRow()" value="Create Row"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label><input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="asynchronous" id="asynchronous">Asynchronous</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="synchronous" id="synchronous">Synchronous</label>
            <div class="asynchronous">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="asyncURL" id="asyncURL" placeholder="Callback URL">
                    <input type="text" id="asyncParam" name="asyncParam[]" placeholder="Param">
                    <input type="button" onclick="createRowAsyc()" value="Create Row" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="synchronous">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" id="syncParam" name="syncParam[]" placeholder="Param">
                    <input type="button" onclick="createRowSync()" value="Create Row" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

I expect the output is `http://test` but the output saved in the file is `http:/\/\test`

please help me solve my problem or anything can help this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` constant to the `json_encode()` like so:

```
 json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Which, for the following input:

```
$data = json_encode([
    "url" => "http://example.com"
], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

will output:

```
{"url":"http://example.com"}
```

As per the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php), this will not escape the slashes:

> **JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES**  Don't escape /. Available as of PHP 5.4.0.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use 
addslashes($nameURL)
This will help you to solve your problem.